# How to provide password authentication for LDAP server in Java?

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, password-protection, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Okay, so I have most of the pieces, but I can't seem to put them together properly. I'm basically trying to protect database data with a simple authentication process (maybe with a GUI) to ensure that the correct people are viewing the data. Right now I'm using UnboundID to handle the actual authentication, although I am open to other methods such as JAAS. Here is the method that I wrote for that (the bypass is for testing purposes):

```
public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    if (username == null || password == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (username.equals("bypass") && password.equals("bypass")) {
        return true;
    }

    try {
        LDAPConnection conn = new LDAPConnection(AUTH_URL,AUTH_PORT);
        BindRequest request = new SimpleBindRequest(username,password);
        BindResult result = conn.bind(request);
        return result.getResultCode().equals(ResultCode.SUCCESS);
    } catch (LDAPException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code is obviously dangerous due to the fact that the password is being inputted as plaintext. I did some digging and discovered that I should be using something like SSL for the actual request to protect the password. This raised another question: if I'm sending the request via SSL, don't I still need to somehow supply the password in plaintext form before I send the request? Isn't this dangerous? I'm surprised something like password authentication isn't done by a simple API since so many applications need to be secure. I'm very new to this stuff and would appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use TLS everywhere including your LDAP connection. As long as you follow good TLS connection practices your connection is safe.
-jim

Comment: Hm, well I suppose using TLS would raise the same question as using SSL. At some point, the user will have to supply a password. I'm a bit confused on how they do so; how can I have them input a password without storing or referencing the plaintext password?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Stormpath's Servlet Plugin](http://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/) to authenticate your users. You only need to follow [these very simple steps](http://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/quickstart.html) to create your ready to use Web Application.

You can also take the example [Servlet App](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/servlet) (completely Open Source) as the foundations for your Web App.

You will get:

1. Out of the box complete Web Application
2. Complete User Management: user authentication, user management, user storage, workflows, etc.
3. [API Management](http://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/http-request-authentication.html)
4. Hassle free [world-class Security](https://stormpath.com/resources/security-and-availability/)
5. Frequent free updates

In summary, the workflow will be like this. You will redirect your users to the [Login page](http://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html) (or [Registration](http://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/registration.html) for them to sign up first). Once your user is properly authenticated (via login) you can get your own code executed via the [Next URI](http://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html#next-uri) or the [SuccessfulAuthenticationRequestEvent](http://docs.stormpath.com/java/servlet-plugin/login.html#events).

Disclaimer, I am an active Stormpath contributor.